# logadm permission issue in Solaris

Tags: permissions, solaris, logrotate

Facing the following issue in a `solaris` box while using `logadm` tool . It is showing me permission denied error .

```
-> logadm -w  princelog  /html/web/www.log -C 3 -s 500m -z 0
logadm: Error: /etc/logadm.conf: Permission denied

-> logadm -C 3 -w  princelog /html/web/www.log  -s 500m -z 0
logadm: Error: /etc/logadm.conf: Permission denied
```

Permission looks fine and the user is `root`.

```
-> ls -l logadm.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root     sys         1684 Jul 15 03:10 logadm.conf

-> id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)

-> chmod 776 logadm.conf
chmod: WARNING: can't change logadm.conf


$ uname -a
SunOS vulhost 5.10 Generic_142900-12 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5140
```

Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you in a read-only zone?

Comment: Sorry , completely new to Solaris. How to identify whether I am in read only zone. Then  what needs to be done to implement the change

Comment: What version of Solaris?  Are you logged in as `root`?

Comment: yeah....user is root as mentioned in original description.                          ` `cat /etc/release
  Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC`

Comment: Read this, then determine if you're in a zone:  http://serverfault.com/questions/153179/how-to-find-out-if-a-solaris-machine-is-virtualized-or-not  If you are in a zone, and `root` can't modify configuration files, you need to work with the system admins of the global zone.

Comment: Since his uname has an architecture of a T5140 , unlikely it's a zone or ldom -- based on memory as I don't have either handy to run a uname in.

I'm curious if a file or a wc -l can be run against /etc/logadm.conf.

Past that, maybe there is a security tool running on the system preventing him access.  ie: HBSS.   
Or it's an odd thing with RBAC?